# How to use akka in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, akka, scala-3, akka-actor

How to use akka in Scala 3 ? I can't find akka dependencies while using scala 3

sbt errors :

```
[error]   not found: /Users/admin/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.15/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.15/akka-actor-typed_3-2.6.15.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor-typed_3:2.6.15
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/admin/.ivy2/localcom.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.15/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.15/akka-actor-typed_3-2.6.15.pom
```

Answer (score 11):

`akka-actor-typed` is published for Scala 2.12, 2.13, not for Scala 3

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed

Try compatibility mode

```
lazy val foo = project.in(file("foo"))
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "3.0.0",
    libraryDependencies += 
      ("com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.15")
        .cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)
  )
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/compatibility-classpath.html

---

**Update.** `akka-actor-typed` is published for Scala 3 since version 2.6.17

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % "2.6.17"
```

Comment: Note that I would not be 100% confident with compatibility mode on such a critical dependency though. But I may be pessimistic :)

Comment: @GaëlJ A quote from the link: "Scala 3 compiler is able to read the Scala 2.13 Pickle format and thus it can type check code that depends on modules or libraries compiled with Scala 2.13. The Scala 3 unpickler has been extensively tested in the community build for many years now. It is safe to use."

Comment: Sure, I mean if it compiles it's probably fine. I was worried about macros stuff (that maybe Akka don't use at all, IDK)

Comment: Scala 3 for akka-actor-typed is since oktober 2021 available

Answer (score 1):

In order to use akka with Scala 3 e.g. the `akka-actor-typed`  you can include [akka-actor-typed 2.6.18](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.18) as a dependency.

The example provided uses [akka-actor-typed 2.6.15](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed_2.13/2.6.15) whose target is scala 2.13 and 2.12.
Scala 3 is included as a target only since [akka-actor-typed 2.6.17](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.17).

The latest version of `akka-actor-typed` where scala 3 is included as a target is [akka-actor-typed 2.6.18](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor-typed_3/2.6.18).